# Route 53 DNS. No nameservers provided an SOA record for the zone

Tags: dns

Using dnsstuff report on my domain, I get:

> No nameservers provided an SOA record for the zone. You should
>   configure your nameservers to have a master slave relationship. The
>   update of the zone information to the slave nameservers should be
>   handled through the SOA record.

The SOA value for the domain is:

```
ns-1520.awsdns-62.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

The NS value for the domain is:

```
ns-1520.awsdns-62.org.
ns-960.awsdns-56.net.
ns-2006.awsdns-58.co.uk.
ns-111.awsdns-13.com.
```

Edit: This was made complicated by me transfering the domain earlier, having the IPs point to the old host for a brief time. I then manually updated the Name Servers to match another domain I have with amazon- Not realizing dns servers for one domain will not work with another.

The solution was:

1) get the name servers assigned by amazon under 'hosted zones', by clicking to right hand side (not clicking the zone name- click to the right of that)

2) under 'Registered domains', make sure the 'Name Servers' match the listed name servers

3) under 'hosted zones' make sure the SOA record matches (SOA should just be the first DNS server on the list.)

4) under the NS records, make sure they match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 4 nameservers you list reply with error code REFUSED for queries on your domain name (why "obfuscating" it anyway?). So there is a problem with AWS Route 53 not handling your domain name correctly, you will need to contact their support/see their help.

Comment: It is not a problem with your registrar: the .COM authoritative nameservers do list your 4 nameservers as authoritative for your domain… however these 4 nameservers are not configured to reply to queries for your domain names. So you need to speak about that with the people managing these 4 nameservers... hence Amazon. I do not use this service so can not help you further.

Comment: The REFUSED could mean that you hit some kind of limits on their service, that your specific domain name is banned for various administrative issues, etc.

Comment: Ok... I think I found my problem... apparently using the name servers for another domain doesn't work for this particular domain. Under the 'hosted zone details' there are 4 different amazon name servers listed. I updated the NS records to reflect those and updated the SOA record to point to the first one on that list. I suppose I should wait a bit for this to take effect to see the results.

Comment: Right now, the authoritative .COM nameservers still list the previous 4 nameservers. Did you go through your registrar (Gandi) to push the new NS list to the .COM registry?

Comment: Gandi is amazon... and I now have the new NS servers set (although dig still shows the old servers). But my understanding is it will take 48 hours to propagate?

Comment: Gandi is not Amazon... The .COM authoritative nameservers reply with the 4 NS listed in your question. If this is not the desired list it means your registrar (Gandi) did not push the update on your domain name at the VeriSign .COM registry.

Comment: The .COM authoritiative nameservers reply for your domain with the 4 NS : ns-538.awsdns-03.net. ns-427.awsdns-53.com. ns-1539.awsdns-00.co.uk. ns-1161.awsdns-17.org.   So this seems to have changed from what you say.

Comment: Yes, I finally have it working (thanks for your help.)